# Implementing "short table" plugin on a custom table

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I've read some examples, searched the thing I want in google ..
Can't really find what I need. also I didn't saw anything about it on the tablesorter
(http://tablesorter.com)

What I basically want to do is to make the plugin work on a custom table. which I created with divs and spans.
It is possible ? If yes, how ?

Comment: Maybe try [tinysort](http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/), or if you want a more detailed answer, share an example of how you want your layout to look.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you displaying a table using `<span>` and `<div>` tags?

The `<table>` syntax is there for a reason, just simply format your table like so:

```
<table id="sortTable" class="tablesorter"> 
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column</th>
            <th>Column</th>
            <th>Column</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And then add the following jQuery code to the bottom of your page

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#sortTable").tablesorter(); 
});
```

Comment: I did it custom because I need to open another div under the table's row. I can't really put div inside the table and make it look like I want it to be.